# Kiwi TCMS & Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, kiwi-tcms

I've landed on Kiwi TCMS as an option for managing our testing system, I had had a brief look and like the look of it - what I'd like to track down before I go much deeper is to see if anyone has experience with how well it works with github actions?

I'd like to know how easy it is to collect the test results, say containing 10'000 tests in JUnit or CPPUnit mixed results formats. And then take these results and see the progression of fixes (or failures) over time. Nothing too fancy to start with...